# How to add multiple records in form for a HMABTM relation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model **Landings** and a model **Products**.

There is a `has_many_and_belongs_to_many` association, with a join table `landings_products`.

I want to be able to add various `products` from the create and edit `landing` form.

I added a select like this where I get a dropdown with selectable products, **but I can only select one product for each landing**, and I want to be able to add as many products as possible:

```
<%= form_with(model: landing, local: true) do |form| %>
    <%= select_tag("landing[product_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all, :id, :name)) %>
    <%= form.submit "Crear landing page", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
<% end %>
```

Also, I've whitelisted the product_ids in the landings controller.

¿How can I add multiple products from the same form for my model?

**Thanks a lot in advance**

Comment: Your select needs to have `multiple: true` chosen if you want to allow multiple selections, plus normally a "size" so that more than one item appears.  However, see obiruby's answer below as the `collection_check_boxes` are almost certainly a better UI choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with [#collection_check_boxes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes):

```
<%= form_with(model: landing, local: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:product_ids, Product.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= form.submit "Crear landing page", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm getting wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 5..7) , what argument is missing?  Maybe :landing should be first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry about that - I originally forgot to include `form` as receiver for the check boxes method. I just updated the answer accordingly.